# json data is not print in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter base application. Here I have write ajax function and pass data to my conttoller. Then it gives an error.

My ajax code is like :

```
$.ajax({
  type:"post",      
  url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/insert_fb",
  data:{record:record,id:id},
  success:function(record_Data){
    alert(record_Data);
  }
});
```

Here, **record** variable pass json data.When I print that record in my controller like :

```
function insert_fb()
{       
    $data = json_decode($this->input->post($record),true);
    print_r($data);
}
```

then it gives an error like

> **Undefined variable : record** and **json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string,array given**.

So, how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$recore` is undefined in your code

```
$data = json_decode($this->input->post($record),true);
```

Instead use

```
$data = json_decode($this->input->post('record'),true);
```

Because you are sending `record` in post data using ajax

I think no need of `json_decode` to get post data using ajax just use

```
$resore=$this->input->post('record');
```